# One div on multiple pages

Tags: html, css

I have a div class on all of my pages. Instead of edit each one manually, is there a way to enter the new parameters somewhere else and have it update across all pages?

The name of the div is `<td class="left_content">`

Comment: That's not a *div*, that's a *td*. They're different things.

Comment: What, if any, templating are you using?

Comment: Hi guys. If you'd like, check it out on SeriousSportsTV dot net   the left side bar with logos is what I would like to do this with.  I'm not the most knowledgeable, I just try to learn as I go. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

No, not with the three technologies (css, html5, css3) you've listed.

You need a dynamic server-side language/framework for building pages out of component pieces, like Ruby on Rails or PHP. These technologies let you programmatically build pages, at which point you can apply standard practices like distilling the commonly retyped bits of code into functions or moving code required in several places into an external included file.

Comment: My server does support PHP and Ruby.  Is there any good info I should read to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I got it.

I created a file, "side.php" with the info I'd like to remain the same on all pages.

Then, in the div where I need the content, I used: <?PHP include "side.php"; ?>


It seems to have implemented on the test page.  Is this the best way to do it. :)

Comment: @user1810581 Yes, that's the way I would do it.  `<?PHP include("side.php"); ?>`.  For organization sake, I keep all my included files in an `/includes/` directory to keep the root cleaner: `<?PHP include("includes/side.php"); ?>`

Comment: The best way to do it would be to pick a PHP MVC framework and learn it.